# has_many, belongs_to issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I am trying to create a list of directors that have many movies (each movie belongs to one director):

```
class Director < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :director

  has_many :movies
end
```

---

```
class Movies < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :director_id, :title, :rating, :boxoffice

  belongs_to :director
end
```

---

My schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130312174246) do

  create_table "directors", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "director"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "movies", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "director_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "rating"
    t.integer  "boxoffice"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

end
```

---

Show in directors controller:

```
 def show
    @director = Director.find(params[:director_id])
    @movies = @director.movies
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @director }
    end
  end
```

---

I would ultimately like to click on a director and see all of the movies he or she has directed, along with the movie's respective ratings and box office $. Currently I get this error: Couldn't find Director without an ID

New to Rails so I'm not sure how to resolve this. Is this the correct setup for what I want to do? If not, how should I change it? Thanks!

Comment: `params[:director_id]` must be nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the director with `params[:id]`, and not with `params[:director_id]`
Try this:

```
@director = Director.find(params[:id])
```

To see all of the movies that a director has made do a nested route:

```
resources :directors do
  resources :movies
end
```

To make all of the actions work in the `MovieController` you have to follow the nested route syntax. Find it here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html or find the rails for zombies 2 tutorial slides on the web, its also nicely explained there.

Comment: Good catch, `rake routes | grep 'directors#show'` should show you `director GET    /directors/:id(.:format)              directors#show`, `:id` is the name of the param given by the URL.

Comment: i just want to add: since you're in the directors controller, it should just be params[:id]

Comment: Thanks guys, this has been really helpful so far! A follow up question: In my Directors show view, what should I include so that when I click on a Director's show link it takes me to his movies etc.? Right now when I click show, it just takes me to the director's name.